# Can't fill in Project Key for quality gates plugin

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I'm trying to user Sonarqube with Jenkins.

I've added the Quality Gates Plugin, to fail the build in Jenkins if the Quality Gates are not respected in Sonarqube.

However, as you can see below, there is no **Project Key** field for Quality Gates.

[image]

Also, if I try to save the configuration, I get:

```
JSONObject["projectKey"] not found.
```

Any idea why this would not appear?

Answer (score 4):

In `http://jenkinsInstance/configure` I had setup SonarQube only in "**SonarQube servers**" but not in "**Quality Gates**" as well.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue. I also didn't initially add the sonar server in the system config, after doing that, I see the Project Key field only in the Post Build Actions.

That doesn't help if you want to add it as a build step or post build step. 
EG. maven install with sonar scan, then test the gate, then if gate passes, maven deploy.

Comment: Quality Gates for Sonarqube only works as a post-build step, apparently. It shouldn't even be showing up in the Build Step list.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure SonarCube Servers first, then configure QualityGates.
This will solve the issue.

Comment: I did the SonarQue sever configuration and nothing, I do not know where or what is causing this error?